# Html2canvas - capture google map to image in phonegap application

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, html2canvas

I want to capture google map with overlays to an image for future uses. I just tried with html2canvas, like

```
 html2canvas($('#map'), {
                        useCORS: true,
                        onrendered: function(canvas) {
                           document.body.appendChild( canvas );
                        }
 });
```

This works fine on desktop browsers like chrome & FF. However in phonegap app it just creates the image with map zoom buttons etc. But map tiles are missing. Just map controlls are there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it.. :)

add `allowTaint:true`

```
html2canvas($('#map'), {
                        useCORS: true,
                        allowTaint:true,
                        onrendered: function(canvas) {
                           document.body.appendChild( canvas );
                        }
 });
```

Comment: Prefer [html2canvas-proxies](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/wiki/Proxies)

Comment: That worked. However, when I move within the map (i.e, I drag it to a different position), the canvas appears incomplete:

http://screencast.com/t/Py4kyTUkUZI

Did you experience that too?

Comment: @jeudyx ya i think i got similar issues. Try google map resize function, after move. Not sure.

Comment: At the end I followed this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046778/html2canvas-does-not-work-with-google-maps-pan and fixed my problem.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the function I've used:

```
function convertasbinaryimage() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("map"), {
        useCORS: true,

        onrendered: function (canvas) {

            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

            img = img.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

            var finalImageSrc = 'data:image/png;base64,' + img;

            $('#googlemapbinary').attr('src', finalImageSrc);

        }
    });
}
```